# Package Ruby Library (permailer) as .jar (using JRuby)

Tags: java, scala, jar, jruby

Essentially, we need to use Premailer (https://github.com/premailer/premailer) as part of our Scala backend, however since it is coded in Ruby we need to use something like`JRuby` so we can execute it on the JVM.

Ideally we would want to create a separate clean `.jar` which just contains `JRuby` (either as a dependency or in the actual JAR itself), Premailer plus a thin `Java` wrapper that would let us call the Premailer API in `Java` (and hence in `Scala`).

The idea is then we would obviously just include the premailer jar as a dependency in our `Scala` backend through `SBT` and just call the thin `Java` wrapper. Does anyone know if there is a tool that lets you do this, or if there is a tutorial on how to do this?

EDIT: It appears a java wrapper already exists, it is here https://github.com/r-shah/java-premailer-wrapper, so it appears its now just a question of packaging it properly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

seems like the work needed to create an interface (so that you abstract away from JRuby's Java/embed APIs) is done - as you've find out.

the project already packages using Maven including [the JRuby jar and the ruby dependencies](https://github.com/r-shah/java-premailer-wrapper/blob/master/pom.xml#L54-L75) for the premailer gem.

while those are not to be found (on Maven Central) they should work as they are auto-generated from https://rubygems.org assets (the rubygems-proxy.torquebox.org does that) ... thus `mvn install` locally and you should be all set

Comment: Thanks, had a look and just noticed it was a simple Maven project. The wrapper I found earlier didn't really work, it used a lot of absolute paths and didn't exactly work with JDK 1.8, so I made my own wrapper here https://github.com/mdedetrich/java-premailer-wrapper and its working like  a charm!

Comment: najs, I will star yours than instead :)